# Neither official nor sweet salutation in letter

Tags: saludos, correspondencia

I know a woman in Spain which is much older than me, I respect her, however our relationship is very informal. Yes, sí la trato de usted, but otherwise our relationship is very informal and friendly - like my grandmother I could say. How should I start letter to her? I don't want to start (say her name is Carmen Jose -  false name):

> ¡Estimada Carmen!

because it sounds very formal and reserved for our relationship (yes she is 80, but she is Spanish! Very friendly). I also don't want to start

> ¡Querida Carmen!

because if I look in the dictionary, this is what lovers use, too sweet, and I don't want anything close to that...

**So please, how should I start (and also end) the letter?
I only found these two phrases which seem to be the opposite extremes!!** I need something in between.

How would you write with your grandma?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Querida Carmen" is perfectly acceptable for non-love-related relations like the one you are describing. It's more like "Dear Carmen" than "My beloved Carmen".

I would not use exclamation marks (EDITED from wrong "admiration marks") to emphasize the salutation. If you *still* use them, please use both the opening and the closing ones. (¡Querida Carmen!)

Letter ending depends strongly on the relation you have with Carmen. "Muchos abrazos" would be adequate for a real grandma, and "Muchos abrazos y besos" too. Do you kiss her like you would kiss your grandma? Do you hug her? If not, just "Abrazos" would do it.

You can complete the ending with personalizations like:

- (Muchos) Abrazos (y besos) de tu querido Tomas
- (Muchos) Abrazos (y besos) de tu Tomas
- (Muchos) Abrazos (y besos) de Tomas

Since you treat her like Usted, maybe:

- Abrazos de Tomas, siempre su amigo

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by "admiration marks"? Didn't you mean "exclamation marks"?

Comment: Yes, exclamation marks is correct. I messed it up while trying to think in spanish and english at the same time!

Comment: Thanks Envite! :-) What about letter ending, what would you choose in this case?

Comment: Edited. Really up to you to decide, since it depends on how exactly your relation is.

Comment: I hug her but not kiss. Then just "abrazos" possibly?

Comment: I should like to know if it might be appropriate to use _Doña_ before _Carmen_ here.

Comment: It depends on if you call her that way on day-to-day conversations

Comment: @Animadversor Using "Doña" in Spain in an informal context would be very strange unless if it's said kidding.

Comment: @JoulSouron even in informal contexts there are occasions, particularly with quite old people, where "Don" or "Doña" is almost another piece of their names.

Comment: @Tomas a truly neutral ending, used with friends and barely known people is just "Saludos". I'd use "Abrazos" only if I wanted to explicitly transmit affection.